# Why ALTER DATABASE .. MODIFY NAME reports an error while succeeding at the same time?

Tags: sql-server

I am running the following query in SSMS:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
ALTER DATABASE [xyz] MODIFY NAME = [xyz_]
```

And get this:

```
The database name 'xyz_' has been set.
Msg 911, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Database 'xyz' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

So, the query fails, but the database is still renamed!

What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is that there's a DDL trigger that fires for ALTER DATABASE, and that trigger code try to refer to the (now old) database name.